# Bundler / Middleman: Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ apply2files (and Gem::FilePermissionError)

Tags: ruby, bundler, middleman

I'm trying to revive a Middleman app from 2014.

When I run `bundle`, I get the following:

```
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ apply2files -
/Users/josua/Documents/Work/MuheimWebdesign/welthaupt/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-1.8.1/.gitignore
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  font-awesome-middleman was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
    middleman-core was resolved to 3.3.4, which depends on
      padrino-helpers was resolved to 0.12.2, which depends on
        padrino-support was resolved to 0.12.2, which depends on
          activesupport was resolved to 4.1.4, which depends on
            json
```

And when running `gem install json -v '1.8.1' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'`, I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

What's interesting is that when I run `ruby -v`, I get a different version than `2.6.0`:

```
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.x86_64-darwin21]
```

Could this be the problem? And if so, how can I make sure that the correct ruby is being used?

Comment: it looks like you've installed your ruby as a global, or by using "sudo" ... have you thought of using `rbenv` or `rvm`?  if you need to run it the way you are, do you want to change the permissions of `/Library/Ruby/Gems` so that your user can write to it?

Comment: I will probably want to install rbenv or rvm, you're right. I'm on a new machine here and didn't think of that.

Comment: I was able to install `rvm` and to update the ruby and gem versions. Needed a bit of trial&error, but now the old project is running again, amazing! :-) Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: no problems. glad you got it working